# Declaring an object with a type which is not declared yet

Tags: c++, struct

Sorry I could not find a better title :) There are two `struct`s in a header file. These `struct`s have members of type another `struct`. Compiler complains that B is not declared when I declare `B obj`. So what should I do?

**structures.h**

```
struct A
{
    B obj; // B is not declared yet
};

struct B
{
    A obj;
};
```

Comment: You can't do that. You will have to change your classes to hold something that does not require the full definition of the other type. For instance, a reference, a pointer, some smart pointers, containers designed to work with incomplete types...

Comment: What would that even *mean*? An instance of A would contain an instance of B would contain an instance of A would contain an instance of A would contain ... ad infinitum.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Could you give an example?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration

Answer (score 0):

Creating an object of type not declared will not be possible. Best you can have is pointer to that type.

An example of use would be like:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A;

struct B{

    A* obj;

    B(){cout<<"B ctr"<<endl;}
};

struct A{

    B* obj;

    A(){cout<<"A ctr"<<endl;}
};


int main()
{
  B obj1;
  obj1.obj = new A();

  A obj2;
  obj2.obj = new B();

   return 0;
}
```